# Editing .cfg leaves Ubuntu server stuck in vi editor

Tags: ubuntu, vi, sudo

I am trying to install some programs on an Ubuntu server (on a virtual machine) by following a tutorial. I am at the part where it says I need to edit a .cfg file. After looking around I found

```
sudo vi /path/file.cfg
```

could be used to edit the file in the command line.

After I typed that, I got a row of:

```
~  
~  
~  
~
```

I pressed enter and now I am stuck in a blank space.

How do I get out of it?  How do I edit and save my .cfg files in command line on an Ubuntu server?

Comment: To exit, press escape to get out of edit mode and type `:Q` I think. Sorry to both you and others if I'm wrong!

Comment: Always remember you can background the active process (normally Ctrl-Z) and/or give it a friendly "bump" from another terminal

Comment: :D I just pressed ctrl+alt twice to get my mouse into my VM and ubuntu restarted! Now how can I edit my .cfg with sudo vi and save it?

Comment: @pst Well I have only one terminal. My ubuntu server doesnt have a GUI.

Comment: Try this link, this should help you. http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/vi.html The link will help you with vi commands.

Comment: Hi All! I tried sudo nano. It gave me a lot of option at the botton. ^X for Exit. When I type it, it doest quite the program.

Comment: sorry. its ctrl+X quits it. Thank you all!

Comment: @prolink 007
Thanks for that link. Ill use that if I dont manage nano well.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using `nano` (or `gedit` if you're graphical) instead of `vi` for beginners. vi/vim is a great editor, but harder to use.

Since you have a blank file up, simply quit by pushing Escape, then `:q!`

Answer (score 1):

Press escape then type :q! and press enter.

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl+C and then try entering :q!

Comment: ctrl-c? what purpose would that serve?

Comment: @KevinDTimm: To make sure they're starting in normal mode, not accidentally in insert mode or replace mode or select mode or visual mode or command mode.  Doesn't get them out of Ex mode but luckily `:q!` works from there too.

Comment: ctrl-c is essentially a no-op in vi.  ESC on the other hand is the key to press to get into command mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you got a column of tilde's, you opened an empty file.

To quit the editor, type `<ESC> :q <ENTER>`

if you want to save your contents, type `<ESC> :x <ENTER>`

Answer (score 0):

To resolve your immediately problem, type `Esc :q!`.

To ensure that vi doesn't show up again unless you explicitly invoke it, you should add the following line to your ~/.bashrc file:

`export EDITOR=emacs`

(Or replace `emacs` with your editor of choice.)

Type `source ~/.bashrc` into your terminal for this change to take effect immediately.